# Remove all non-ASCII characters from a string except smart quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex that removes all non-ascii characters from a string including all smart quotes:

```
str.replace(/[\u{0080}-\u{FFFF}]/gu,"");
```

But I need to keep the Smart quotes

The regex for removing Smart single quotes is: `[\u2018\u2019\u201A\u201B\u2032\u2035]` and for Smart double quotes is: `[\u201C\u201D\u201E\u201F\u2033\u2036]`.

I need a combined regex that that removes all non-ASCII (`[\u{0080}-\u{FFFF}]`) except smart quotes (`[\u2018\u2019\u201A\u201B\u2032\u2035]` or `[\u201C\u201D\u201E\u201F\u2033\u2036]`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you need to use the `\u{XXXX}` notation in the regex with `u` modifier, and to build the regex you need you need to put the character class with exceptions into a negative lookahead placed right before your more generic pattern:

```
/(?![\u{2018}\u{2019}\u{201A}\u{201B}\u{2032}\u{2035}\u{201C}\u{201D}\u{201E}\u{201F}\u{2033}\u{2036}])[\u{0080}-\u{FFFF}]/gu
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kTeb2N/2/)

Note that some chars in the Unicode table go one after another, so we may shorten the pattern using ranges:

```
/(?![\u{2018}-\u{201F}\u{2032}\u{2033}\u{2035}\u{2036}])[\u{0080}-\u{FFFF}]/gu
```

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/kTeb2N/3).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of matching the non-ascii, match the ascii + the characters you need, and negate the expression. Example:

```
str.replace(/[^\x00-\x7F\u2018\u2019\u201A\u201B\u2032\u2035\u201C\u201D\u201E\u201F\u2033\u2036]/gu,"");
```